# Subclass enum variable initialize

Tags: ios, swift, enums, subclass

I have this class and i've added an enum called GradientDirection, I want to initialize it with a value at start, how could I do that as I did with the colors variable?

```
enum GradientDirection {
    case Horizontal
    case Vertical
}

class GradientColorView : UIView {

    var colors : NSArray = NSArray() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var direction : GradientDirection. {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var topRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height / 2.0)
        var firstColor : UIColor = self.colors[0] as! UIColor
        firstColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(topRect)

        var bottomRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height/2.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0)
        var secondColor : UIColor = self.colors[1] as! UIColor
        secondColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(bottomRect)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var direction : GradientDirection = GradientDirection.Horizontal {`

Comment: I have an error when doing like this: `'Horizontal' is not a member type of 'GradientDirection'`

Comment: David's code works for me.  Check for typos